# HighChart border color on rotated labels

Tags: rotation, highcharts, border

I'm playing around with highchart label feature.

I've tried some border colors, it works fine except if I use a rotation with it.

As demonstrated in this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ZZpty/) :

```
dataLabels: {
             align: 'left',
             enabled: true,
             rotation: 270, //if the rotation is 0, the border is working fine.
             x: 2,
             y: -10,
             //added for test purpose :
               borderColor: 'rgba(252, 0, 197, 0.7)',
               borderRadius: 3,
               borderWidth: 2
}
```

when a rotation is set, the border doesn't apply the same way.

seems like a bug to me.

can you explain this and maybe provide a workaround  for this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known bug, reported to our devs here https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/1334